# React's Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo after building with webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, webpack

I'm trying to build this package:
https://github.com/searchkit/searchkit/ (version v0.10.1)

with webpack and use this with my modules:

- node v6.1.0
- npm v3.8.6

Build strategy:

1. fetch repository from github
2. npm install
3. npm run build

inside /node_modules/

nothing special is done.

But after trying to use this module withun my components I get those cases.

Case is that if I build with:
searchkit/src/core/react/SearchkitProvider.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import {SearchkitManager} from "../SearchkitManager"

export interface SearchkitProps {
    searchkit:SearchkitManager
    children?:any
}

export class SearchkitProvider extends React.Component<SearchkitProps,any> {

    static childContextTypes = {
        searchkit:React.PropTypes.instanceOf(SearchkitManager)
    }

    static propTypes = {
        searchkit:React.PropTypes.instanceOf(SearchkitManager).isRequired,
        children:React.PropTypes.element.isRequired
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.searchkit.setupListeners()
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.searchkit.completeRegistration()
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.props.searchkit.unlistenHistory()
    }

    getChildContext(){
        return {searchkit:this.props.searchkit}
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>IT DOES WORK!!</div>
        );
    }
}
```

using by

```
class Listing extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (
       <div>
            <SearchkitProvider searchkit={searchkit}>
                <div></div>
              </SearchkitProvider>          
       </div>
       );
    }
}
```

It DOES work properly with proper response, but If I change module's source to:

```
export class SearchkitProvider extends React.Component<SearchkitProps,any> {

    (...)

    render(){
        return (
            <div><input ref="REF" /></div>
        );
    }
}
```

it throws this error Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded.

I'm not really sure what dependency is made while I'm doing that kind of change ? Should I look for duplicated React instances even though it's working when I'm not using input with ref ?

Webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const copyrightBanner = require("fs").readFileSync("./COPYRIGHT", "utf-8")
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "ignore":['./theming/index.ts'],
    "bundle":['./src/index.ts']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'release'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library:["Searchkit"],
    libraryTarget:"umd",
    publicPath: '',
    css: 'theme.css'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions:[".js", ".ts", ".tsx","", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".scss"],
    alias: { react: path.resolve('../react') }
  },
  postcss: function () {
    return [autoprefixer]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin(copyrightBanner, {entryOnly:true}),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("theme.css", {allChunks:true}),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      mangle: {
        except: ['require', 'export', '$super']
      },
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        conditionals: true,
        booleans: true,
        unused: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
        drop_console: true
      }
    })
  ],
  externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom":"ReactDOM"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loaders: ['ts'],
        include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'),path.join(__dirname, 'theming')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(require.resolve("style-loader"),require.resolve("css-loader")+"!"+require.resolve("postcss-loader")+"!"+require.resolve("sass-loader")),
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'theming')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        loaders: [
            'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
        ],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'theming')
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

npm ls react:

```
├── react@0.14.8
└─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY searchkit@0.10.1
  └── react@0.14.8

npm ERR! peer dep missing: searchkit@0.9.x, required by searchkit-multiselect@0.0.1
```